# ng-options orderBy value in key value pairs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I am not able to order a key value pair with respect to `value` in **alphabetical order**.

The sample which I am using is,

```
"week_days_short":[
    {"key":"1","value":"Mon"},
    {"key":"2","value":"Tue"},
    {"key":"4","value":"Thu"},
    {"key":"3","value":"Wed"},
    {"key":"5","value":"Fri"},
    {"key":"6","value":"Sat"},
    {"key":"7","value":"Sun"}
]
```

I have used the following code,

```
ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in 
            properties.week_days_short | 
            orderBy:'value' track by value"
```

But the sorting not happening. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As orderBy in HTML won't work on Object and week_days_short is array. So sorting on controller fixed my issue.

```
Object.values($scope.properties.week_days_short).sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

$scope.properties = {
  "week_days_short":[
    {"key":"1","value":"Mon"},
    {"key":"2","value":"Tue"},
    {"key":"4","value":"Thu"},
    {"key":"3","value":"Wed"},
    {"key":"5","value":"Fri"},
    {"key":"6","value":"Sat"},
    {"key":"7","value":"Sun"}
  ]};

})
```

```html
 <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    selection={{selection}}<br>
    Select with Alphabetical Order<br>
    <select ng-model="selection"
            ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in 
              properties.week_days_short | 
              orderBy:'value' track by item.value">
      <option value="">Select day</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

### The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/EzjmjhV7JiQYdGXXvl4a?p=preview)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)
- [AngularJS ng-options Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: The code you have shared is perfectly working if the input is array. But my input was object, so I ended up writing a sort function in controller.

Answer (score -2):

I think it can help you.

```
ng-options="key as value.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key)) for (key, value) in 
        properties.week_days_short | 
        orderBy:'value' track by value"
```

Here is Ref: [In ES6/ES2015 or later you can do this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092754/8509803)

Comment: Fat arrow functions are not allowed in AngularJS expressions. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - JavaScript vs AngularJS Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).